# Character Animation Library

Tags: animation, game-engine

I am looking for character animation library which can be included in my game engine.

I prefer FOSS but, paid is good if it's price is reasonable.

So, far what Ive found is [Cal3d](http://gna.org/projects/cal3d/).But it looks dead.

Can anyone tell, what are the other options?

I am also interested in Havok Animation which comes in the free bundle of Havok. Any thoughts about this one?

**EDIT:** language is C++

Comment: You would probably get better answers over on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, just in case someone stumble upon this question, I am answer so far what Ive found,

**Open Source:**

[Animadead](http://animadead.sourceforge.net/) - Development stopped at 2006

[Cal3d](http://home.gna.org/cal3d/) - Development stopped at 2007

[Alienmotion](http://www.chemical-games.com/?page_id=1057) - This one is underdevelopment but still looks very polished

[HALCA (Hardware Accelerated Library for Character Animation)](http://www.lsi.upc.edu/~bspanlang/animation/avatarslib/doc/) - Check it out.

[D A N C E - Dynamic Animation and Control Environment](http://www.arishapiro.com/dance/) - wicked, but so far what I know is, it's not allowed to use for commercial purpose.

**Commercial :**

[IKinema](http://www.ikinema.com/IKinema_-_lifelike_animation,_run-time_or_off-line.html)

[HavokAnimation](http://www.havok.com) - Free to use if you are happy with only windows, and games wont cost more then 10usd.(subjective)

[Autodesk HumanIK](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/index?id=9491249&siteID=123112) - I wish, this had a indie friendly license

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use libraries from Blender. http://www.blender.org/